# Server side caching vs client side caching to maintain a key-value map

Tags: php, mysql, caching, extjs, redis

I have a web app written with `extjs` and a `php` backend. The backend has access to databases `A` and `B`. The app contains various grids which display a lot of user information; Whats important for this problem is the `userID` which is displayed in most grids as a separate column.

**The problem**

For some reasons, the `userID` in DB `B` has to be replaced by a user's `accountID`. But the front-end still has to display the user's `userID`. Which means I have to have some form of a mapping between `userID` - `accountID` to maintain the expected functionality.

Please note that the userID -> accountID mapping is available in the database A

**Potential Solutions**

**Server-side cache** -
There are approximately 10000 users. One option I have considered is a server-side cache such as a `redis` to maintain this mapping. But this would still need query results to be parsed in the backend and each `userID` replaced with the corresponding `accountID` and sent to the front-end. So for example, 500 resultant rows from a query would mean 500 `redis` calls to obtain the corresponding `userID` (?) Performance might be an issue here.

**Client-side cache** -
Use a client-side storage option such as `LocalStorage`, `LocalForage` or even a simple `hashmap` and load the mapping details from the `redis` to the front-end. Then when the grid data is being rendered, use this map to obtain the corresponding `userID`.

The mapping has to work the other way around as well, when sending data from the app to the database.

There are also issues like keeping the `redis` updated with the DB as there can be scenarios where a user information could change. Then the client-side cache will also need to be updated. All these things need to be considered as a part of the solution.

I would appreciate some feedback and any other potential solutions I could look at to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you mean that userID and accountID have the same value for the same user?

Comment: @LiamG it is a one to one mapping, but no the values are not the same

Comment: But there is some sort of link in the tables? You could avoid mapping in your code and just join the tables in your SQL, as regards to caching, I would use stringified JSON in localStorage

Comment: @LiamG it's too complex to explain, but in a nutshell, the userID is entirely being replaced by the accountID within database B. The mapping information is only available in database A. The user experience has to remain the same, meaning the front-end still has to display the userID.

Comment: You can add another column to your table: `userID` (or `accountID`), the one of them that doesn't exist. Then run a script to update all of them to the correct value. And also handle this for new users of course.

Comment: So am I right in thinking there is an accountID in table A?

Comment: The backend has access to database A. Which other means are there to update database A, apart from that backend?

Comment: @HtmHell changing the db schema is not an option

Comment: @LiamG not table, database. and the userID -> accountID mapping is available in database A

Comment: @Alexander there are multiple other components that update database A. but none of that can be used as a solution for this. Also I forgot to mention, the userID - accountID mapping is available in database A.

Comment: "So for example, 500 resultant rows from a query would mean 500 redis calls" Do you really have this kind of quey? with so many rows?

Comment: Since you already have the mapping in database A it's not clear why you don't just use that to do the lookup. It's equivalent to your Redis case, just using SQL instead of Redis. (And note that in both the SQL case and the Redis case you can look up indefinitely many ids in a single call; you don't need a separate lookup for each id.)

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry DB A is a sharded database that exists in a different server. Retrieving the mapping details from A every time a grid loads its data will be a very costly operation.

Comment: If you must add a new system, then the Redis solution sounds like the best and simplest option. Performance should not be an problem. You can look up 500 IDs in a single call and the lookup time will be miniscule. By far the ugliest problem will be keeping it in sync with your database.